# What is the difference between httpCompression and urlCompression?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, compression, gzip

Looking at the  node in a Web.config, I see that it allows both httpCompression and urlCompression elements. What's the difference between the two? I just want to do standard gzip, which one should I use?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**urlCompression** specifies **what** to compress and **httpCompression** indicates **how** to do the compression. If you're running on IIS7.5, you don't need to specify anything, both dynamic and static compression are enabled by default, both use gzip; here are some links on [urlCompression](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/urlCompression) and [httpCompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786638/how-can-i-get-gzip-compression-in-iis7-working).