# gzip not working in iis7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get gzip compression in IIS7 working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786638/how-can-i-get-gzip-compression-in-iis7-working)

I have enabled static compression on iis7.5 but my .js and .css files are not getting compressed.

**my web.config**

```
<staticContent><remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
</staticContent><httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>      

    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

Still YSlow Grad: F. Any ideas?

Comment: does why-slow something in  GZIP(KB) column with values? Some time firewall unzip the response sent by the ISS. I have faced the same problem and the network team told me the firewall can unzip the response before sending sending or your firewall from where you are accessing can unzip

Comment: No.It is empty and also i checked with "http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php"

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
```

to:

```
    <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true"/>
```

for both entries (under dynamictypes and static types).